# Downsides of Twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, restivejs

I have been building website using my custom CSS and HTML for along time now. Just a minute ago I discovered Bootstrap.

So, I want to here from the people who have experienced hair pulling issues with bootstrap.

P.S. If you had to make a site responsive, would you use Bootstrap or Restive.JS?

Comment: Those two products aren't really comparable. Restive.js appears to be primarily geared toward making your content responsive. Bootstrap is a full-featured component and effects library that happens to include a responsive grid option. That said, the only people I've encountered who pull their hair when using Bootstrap are those who don't read the docs and try to implement it with a sloppy approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just finished re-skinning a site using Bootstrap over custom classes.

Overall, I'm now a Bootstrap fan.  what I found was

- First thing to keep in mind is to do things the Bootstrap way.  It uses css classes to define what needs to be done.  Then the framework's JavaScript will sense those classes and add the appropriate actions.
- Using the grid makes it easy to have a consistent layout across each page.
- You probably need to tweak some of the layout classes on a page to solve local layout issues.

I haven't used Restive.JS, but it appears to solve the responsive design issues completely differently from Bootstrap.

Overall, I would suggest you try both and see which meets your needs best.